# Intuition behind definition for limits at infinity using epsilons and deltas

Tags: real-analysis

> f is said to have a limit at infinity, if there exists a real number L such that for all $\epsilon>0, \exists N>0$ such that  $|f(x) -L|< \epsilon $,$\forall x > N$. In otherwords:
> $$ \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) = L$$
> [(from)](https://brilliant.org/wiki/epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit/#infinite-limit-at-infinity)

I don't understand here why we say $\exists N>0$, why not refer to real numbers ?  I don't think we lose any information doing it this way and it is more intuitive because when we discuss concepts of continuity and differentiability in real analysis, we use the set $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure. You are right. It's just a matter of tradition.

Comment: Where did this tradition originate ? :-) @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: I don't know. That's a question that you could post at the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: The tradition probably comes from the similarity to limits of sequences, where it makes sense to consider only naturals. And maybe because it's a nice pedagogical opportunity to illustrate the Archimedean property, which makes the definitions using reals and naturals equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the definition of limit you quote says $N\in \mathbb{N}$. In fact, I've seen $N\in \mathbb{R}$ used in the definition before. That's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_limits_at_infinity) uses.

I would imagine the notation of using the letter $N$ (which is typically used in reference to natural numbers) comes from limits of sequences, as Vercassivelaunos suggests, where we want to show that it holds beyond some $n$th element of the sequence, and where $N\in \mathbb{N}$ arises naturally since you can think of a real-valued sequence $\{a_n\}$ as a function mapping between $n\in \mathbb{N} \to a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: At least this is what I also learnt. +1 limits of sequences are different from that of functions in this regard.